# Autoloading using Namespaces, trouble understanding scope and inheritence

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, frameworks, psr-4

**Background**

I am trying to build up my own personal MVC framework from scratch for my own education... for help with this question I have stripped back the framework to an extremely simplified level.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/JethroHazelhurst/psr-4-mvc

I am using the PSR-4 standard to autoload classes so my Namespaces follow my directory structure.

**What I have so far**

Here is my directory structure

[image]

On my index page I have my Autoloader and am instantiating a Core\Router class.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $root = dirname(__DIR__);   // directory - e.g. http://www.example.com
    $file = $root . '/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php'; // adds a leading slash and replaces '\' with '/'
    // checks if the file exists and is readable
    if (is_readable($file)) {
        require $file; // if it is then the file is required
    }
});

$mountain = new Core\Router;

$mountain->instantiateController();
$mountain->callAction();
```

In my Core\Router class I have two functions, the first:

1. instantiate the \App\Controllers\Everest controller.
2. calls the loadModel() function which is in the parent 'Master' Controller

The second:

1. Calls an action (about()) in the instantiated 'Everest' controller

```
Namespace Core;

class Router
{
    public function instantiateController()
    {
        $this->_controller = new \App\Controllers\Everest(); // hard coded
        $this->_controller->loadModel('Sherpas'); // hard coded
    }

    public function callAction()
    {
        $this->_controller->about(); // hard coded
    }
}
```

Next, in my Everest controller class I have a parent constructor and one method.

```
<?php

Namespace App\Controllers;

class Everest extends \Core\Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $this->view->test = $this->model->hello();
        $this->view->render('AboutEverest');
    }
}
```

In my 'Master Controller' which all other controllers inherit I instantiate a new master 'View' class. This master controller is where the 'loadModel() function is.

```
<?php

Namespace Core;

class Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View;
    }



    public function loadModel($name)
    {
        $path = '../App/Models/' . $name . '_Model.php';

        if (file_exists($path)) {

            require $path;

            $modelName = '\App\Models\Sherpas_Model';

            $model = new $modelName;
            return $model;
        }
    }
}
```

**Issues and Errors**

I am having a hard time understanding how the objects and classes are interacting within the framework and even formulating a question is difficult for me.

I am getting this error

[image]

**Question**

Why am I getting this error?

Personally I think it is because all my controllers are in a different Namespace (App\Controllers) to their parent controller (Core).

If this is in fact the case, what is the best way to get this thing working?

Many thanks in advance to you wonderful PHPers!

** UPDATE **

The answer below was the solution.. you can see the updated code here with a very simple database wrapper: https://github.com/JethroHazelhurst/psr-4-mvc

Comment: If you have this `$root = dirname(__DIR__);` in your index.php, you actually setting the `$root` to `/path/to/public` while the rest of your code is one step up. Try change it to: `$root = __DIR__ . '/..';`. And you don't need to wrap the `__DIR__` in `dirname()` since they do the same. And you're controllers can extend classes from other namespaces without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i try your code...I will not comment your code and I will provide your answer:

to the class Controller, `Core\Controller.php` you need to add protected property model and save your new model to this property in loadModel method

```
class Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View;
    }



    public function loadModel($name)
    {
        $path = '../App/Models/' . $name . '_Model.php';
        if (file_exists($path)) {

            require $path;

            $modelName = '\App\Models\Sherpas_Model';

            $model = new $modelName;
            $this->model = $model;
        }
    }
}
```

if you want, I can do some merge requests to your repository for some modifications which can help you

Comment: And since he's using PSR-4 Autoloading, there's no need to `require $path`, since that is what the autoloader does for you.

Comment: Plus... the `require` loads the file dynamically while the instantiation have a hard coded model name.

Comment: Oh my, this is some fantastic code, I was working on another solution but this looks great and I don't have to mess around with passing variables  to parent constructors etc... I have a tone of experimenting to do, thanks!

Comment: And regarding the merge request, that would be much appreciated, but only if you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: Fantastic, your original answer was the solution. great help, thanks!